# Error while connecting to data using Modem Manager in Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, modem, networkmanager, raspbian-buster

I am using Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3 with Raspbian Buster OS. I have connected Quectel EC25 modem and trying to connect to internet using Network Manager and Modem Manager tool.

Whenever I use new Airtel or Vodafone SIM cards, either `Couldn't connect bearer: 'QMI protocol error (14): 'CallFailed''`  or `couldn't start network: QMI protocol error (79): 'PolicyMismatch'` error occurs. After random hours (max. 50 hours), this error gets resolve and connection is being established successfully. I am not able to figure out what exactly the issue is.

List of error as per logs:

```
Jan  4 15:43:52 24Seven-78 ModemManager[6574]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Registered 'wds' (version 1.67) client with ID '22'
Jan  4 15:43:52 24Seven-78 ModemManager[6574]: <info>  error: couldn't start network: QMI protocol error (79): 'PolicyMismatch'
Jan  4 15:43:52 24Seven-78 ModemManager[6574]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Allocating new client ID...
Jan  4 15:43:52 24Seven-78 ModemManager[6574]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Registered 'wds' (version 1.67) client with ID '23'
Jan  4 15:43:52 24Seven-78 ModemManager[6574]: <info>  error: couldn't start network: QMI protocol error (14): 'CallFailed'
Jan  4 15:43:52 24Seven-78 ModemManager[6574]: <info>  call end reason (1): 'generic-unspecified'
Jan  4 15:43:52 24Seven-78 ModemManager[6574]: <info>  verbose call end reason (2,237): [internal] (null)
```

```
Jan  4 16:46:54 24Seven-78 ModemManager[6574]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1: state changed (registered -> connecting)
Jan  4 16:46:54 24Seven-78 NetworkManager[535]: <info>  [1609759014.9170] modem["cdc-wdm0"]: modem state changed, 'registered' --> 'connecting' (reason: user-requested)
Jan  4 16:46:55 24Seven-78 ModemManager[6574]: <info>  error: couldn't start network: QMI protocol error (14): 'CallFailed'
Jan  4 16:46:55 24Seven-78 ModemManager[6574]: <info>  call end reason (1): 'generic-unspecified'
Jan  4 16:46:55 24Seven-78 ModemManager[6574]: <info>  verbose call end reason (6,55): [3gpp] multiple-connection-to-same-pdn-not-allowed
Jan  4 16:46:55 24Seven-78 ModemManager[6574]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Allocating new client ID...
```

QMI Protocol Error 2,237 means `ip-support-mismatch` and 6,55 means `multiple-connection-to-same-pdn-not-allowed`. I am not able to understand these and how to resolve them.

Following is the Network Manager connection details:

```
[connection]
id=MobileConnection
uuid=67bfdda8-e92d-4407-880d-eaf3294a5180
type=gsm
autoconnect-priority=3
interface-name=cdc-wdm0
permissions=

[gsm]
apn=www
number=*99#

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto
route-metric=50

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

I am attaching debug logs of Modem Manager.

[Logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B0JujG_CZpuGaARKd8MgHJ4sKZ6MqY7e/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Tarurun Malviya did you figure this out?

Comment: @lucaswxp Yes. Two points:
1. Let me explain this with an example. Let's say I have one new Airtel SIM card and the APN of Airtel is `airtelgprs.com`. If I first try to connect to GSM network by setting APN as `www`, the connection successfully establishes irrespective of whether APN is correct or not. Now, when I try to connect to GSM network with correct APN, i.e., `airtelgprs.com`, then it throws error mentioned in the description.
2. The SIM card is not activated.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, I've logged an issue https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mobile-broadband/ModemManager/-/issues/665